# There is some kind of real or complex analysis over graphs?

Tags: analysis, graph-theory, reference-request, soft-question

This is a soft question, it just comes from my curiosity and, probably, it doesn't make sense. I will delete the question if needed.

This is the thing: I was studying a bit of basic harmonic analysis and I realized that we can see periodic functions over the real line as just functions over the unit circle in the complex plane, then with this isomorphism a Fourier series take the form of a power series, and it play a role similar to the role that a Maclaurin series plays for an analytic function on $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$.

Thus I thought that people have the tendency to represent functions in a planar geometry, because it seems simpler and more natural, in the Cartesian plane. However it would be possible that many beautiful mathematics can be seen better using a different representation, as functions over a more exotic geometry than a plane.

Also, from basic knowledge of topology, I know that geometries like a cross of the kind $X:=([-1,1]\times \{0\})\cup (\{0\}\times [-1,1])$ are not locally homeomorphic to an Euclidean space, so my question is: there is some kind of real (or complex) analysis of functions over geometries that are not locally Euclidean, like a finite graph? If so, can someone recommend some reference or bibliography to take a look at the subject? Thank you in advance.